# Tag merge: should we merge "computer-vision" with "vision"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There are two tags that seem to be referring to the same subject:

- [computer-vision](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision)
- [vision](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vision)

Should we merge these? If I remember correctly from the previous discussion, we decided to drop the "computer" prefix for these tags.

Comment: I don't see why not. Let's wait and see whether there are other thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've merged [vision](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vision) into [computer-vision](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision), because [as Paresh remarks](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/569/tag-merge-should-we-merge-computer-vision-with-vision/570#570) this does seem to be the dominant usage even in the field. It's easy to reverse the direction of the synonym if we develop the opposite preference.

Comment: People I know who work in vision regularly refer to their area as vision however I don't have a strong opinion about which one should be the main tag so thanks for merging.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure of what the guidelines are for naming tags, but here are my 2 cents. As far as I have seen, this area is generally formally referred to as Computer Vision, and not Vision. Most courses and book names use Computer Vision. The Wiki article is titled [Computer Vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision). One can even see the use of Computer Vision in questions from students, such as [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7050/differences-between-computer-vision-and-image-processing).

Keeping the computer-vision tag offers the additional benefit that when searching for the tag when asking a question, if the user starts typing "vision", he will still be shown the "computer-vision" tag in the suggested tags (search looks for matching tag substrings), while someone typing "computer-vision" would also be shown the right tag in the suggested tags, though it may take longer to show up.

I guess dropping the "computer-" prefix makes sense in that the prefix is redundant on a CS site. But I still feel that computer-vision might be a better option. Of course, on the issue of merging of tags, please go ahead. Which one needs to be kept is the question.

Comment: IIRC the argument was that on this site vision is not ambiguous, the tag will refer to computer-vision. Also we can make the longer tag a *synonym* for the shorter one so it will keep showing up in the suggested tags list when typing.

Comment: Aah, I was not aware that this could be done, though after looking it up, I realized I had seen synonyms before :). Maybe we should have a section on tagging in the FAQ, but that is another discussion. Your suggestion of keeping "computer-vision" as a synonym sounds good.